# Getting spaces, If goes with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had created header & side nav bar.
Whenever I used the CDN of bootstrap Iam getting the spaces around header and sidenav bar as like below image:
[Click here for image ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxQhs.png)

```
<style>
#mySidenav a {
position: absolute;
left: -80px;
transition: 0.3s;
padding: 15px;
width: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
left: 0;
}
#mySidenav a:focus{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
#about {
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
    top: 150px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
top: 250px;
background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
top: 350px;
background-color: #555;
}
.divleft {
 margin-left :100px;
 height :500px;

}
header{


padding: 1rem;
color: white;
background-color: black;
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}
article {
margin-left: 170px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
padding: 1em;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
}
.sidenav a {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
</style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/
  css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mySidenav a').on('click', function () {
        $('a.fixed').removeClass('fixed');
        $(this).addClass('fixed');
    });


    $('.divleft').hide();

    $("#about").click(function () {

        $("#abt").show();
        $("#blg").hide();
        $("#prj").hide();
        $("#cnt").hide();
        $(".openDiv").hide();

    });


    $("#blog").click(function () {

        $("#abt").hide();
        $("#blg").show();
        $("#prj").hide();
        $("#cnt").hide();
        $(".openDiv").hide();
    });


    $("#projects").click(function () {

        $("#abt").hide();
        $("#blg").hide();
        $("#prj").show();
        $("#cnt").hide();
        $(".openDiv").hide();
    });

    $("#contact").click(function () {
        window.location.href = "/Home/Index"
        $("#abt").hide();
        $("#blg").hide();
        $("#prj").hide();
        $("#cnt").show();
        $(".openDiv").hide();
        });
   });

</script>
 <body style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
<div class="container">

<header style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
   <h1>Irawath User</h1>
</header>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="position:absolute">
  <a href="#" id="about">Appointment</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">MemberShip</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Profile</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Log Out</a>
</div>

<article>
   <div style="margin-left :100px;height :500px;" class="openDiv">

   </div>
   <div id="abt" class="divleft">
 Appointment
  <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="blg" class="divleft">
MemberShip
</div>

<div id="prj" class="divleft">
Profile
</div>

<div id="cnt" class="divleft">
Log Out
</div>
</article>

 <footer>Copyright &copy; Irawath</footer>

</div>
    </body>
```

How can I overcome those spaces even after using the bootstrap ?

Comment: It looks like the header is using a `.container` and the body is using `.container-fluid`.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb , Thanks that's the issue. But still i'm facing the sidenavbar. Still I'm getting spaces for side navigation.

Comment: So give it a `-15px` margin on the sides.

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem.

Comment: Just a note on using Bootstrap: I recommend not using in-line styles but rather create custom classes you can drive yourself crazy trying to figure those out later

Comment: Okay, I'll follow it. I'm very beginner to this bootstrap.